# Append multiple file and change value in R

Tags: r, csv, replace

I have a problem in R. I have a file file with this record:

```
[2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId: ]
```

and I would like to remove the `"["` and `"]"` and transform the row in this way (like a CSV):

```
2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00;XFM;ERROR:1;EPMHFM-00832;XFM;ecid: ;File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp;Line: 840;userId: ;
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` as well. 
***update***: If you have only one column where you need to apply the replacement function. Then apply the `gsub` , replace x in below with `df$colname`. Where df is your dataframe and colname is the name of the column you are trying to apply the gsub function.

```
x = "[2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832]
     [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId:  ]"

# replace '[' with "" in the x variable
result = gsub("(\\[)", "", x)
# replace ']' with ";" in the result variable
result = gsub("(\\])", ";", result)
result
```

---

output

```
2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00; XFM; ERROR:1; EPMHFM-00832;
XFM; ecid: ; File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp; Line: 840; userId:  ;
```

Comment: And if I have a dataframe?

Comment: use `apply` or `lapply` functions. Update your question with dataframe

Comment: I have pubblic my dataframe, in qhich way i can use apply?

Answer (score 0):

using `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)    
your_var = str_replace_all(your_var, "\\[", "")
your_var = str_replace_all(your_var, "\\]", ";")
```

or

```
your_var = str_replace_all(your_var, "\\[|\\]", "")
write.csv(your_var, your_path)
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your_var ?

Comment: `your_var = "[2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832]
     [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId:  ]"` or replace `your_var ` with the variable inside your data.frame, like `df$variable = str_replace_all...`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, I have a dataframe with only one column

Comment: if you have a data.frame called `df`, with one variable called `x`, you just have to do `df$x = str_replace_all(df$x, "\\[", "")` and `df$x = str_replace_all(df$x, "\\]", ";")`

Answer (score -1):

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 8492] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 8004024B] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 2] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] The session has become invalid, a logoff is needed. [[]]

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 8492] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 8004024B] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 2] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] The session has become invalid, a logoff is needed. [[]]

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.158521+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 8492] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 8004024B] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 2] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] The session has become invalid, a logoff is needed. [[]]

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.174141+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-07274] [XFM] [ecid: 00iipfc_C4AFw00Fzzw0w00001iK002EVK] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 1316] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 14932] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 80040275] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 1] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] Invalid session ID. Your session may have expired, or your administrator may have logged you out. Please try to log in again. [[]]

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.174141+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-07274] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 1316] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 14932] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 80040275] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 1] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] Invalid session ID. Your session may have expired, or your administrator may have logged you out. Please try to log in again. [[]]

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.189772+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 14932] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 8004024B] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 2] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] The session has become invalid, a logoff is needed. [[]]

[2017-10-30T15:40:52.189772+01:00] [XFM] [ERROR:1] [EPMHFM-00832] [XFM] [ecid: ] [File: CXdsSessionManager.cpp] [Line: 840] [userId: ] [appName: ONE] [pid: 14264] [tid: 14932] [host: APP57GBFW] [nwaddr: 151.88.223.46:0;172.23.200.193:0;151.87.82.240:0;169.254.95.120:0;] [errorCode: 8004024B] [srcException: XfmExc] [errType: 1] [dbUpdate: 2] [11.1.2.4.203.5250] The session has become invalid, a logoff is needed. [[]]
....

This is my dataframe

Comment: you should edit the question. Not post it as an answer. Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example